# navigating to new page does not cause previous page to be unmounted

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-router, ionic4

I have a simple ionic app with an `IonReactRouter`

```
<IonApp>
  <IonReactRouter>
    <IonSplitPane contentId="main">
      <Menu selectedPage={selectedPage} />
      <IonRouterOutlet id="main">
      <Route path="/new-user" component={NewUser}  />
      <Route path="/users" component={UserList}  />
      </IonRouterOutlet>
    </IonSplitPane>
  </IonReactRouter>
</IonApp>
```

When you navigate between `new-user` and `users` the corresponding pages (`NewUser` and `UserList`)  are not unmounted:

[image]

According to [this post](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/20105#issuecomment-567166301) this is by design

> we need to control and keep pages around in the dom even if a user navigates away from them for page transition and state purposes

However I find that most end users expect clicking on 'New User' to show a fresh copy of the page. How can i make the page be unmounted OR achieve the same goal and 'reset' the page when a link is clicked?

Comment: Could you provide an online demo? I would like to make that HOC based on the demo, as long as you have no idea how to implement it

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Ionic Lifecycle events to reset the state of your form each time the user navigates to the new user page. IonViewWillEnter will fire each time the page is displayed, even though it is already mounted by React.

Check out the docs for usage information: https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/lifecycle

Comment: I've added all 4 lifecycle methods as per the docs to my functional component `NewUser` but none of them are firing - there are no errors - what could that be?

Comment: @wal are they descendants of an IonReactRouter? Its needed for the events to fire.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "key" to "IonRouterOutlet" component and update it on route changed.

An example for Vue:

```
<ion-router-outlet :key="route.fullPath" ></ion-router-outlet>
```